# Redux: Style Guide confusion on connecting more components to the store

Tags: redux, react-redux

According to Redux Style Guide, it is **strongly recommended** to [connect more components to read data from the store](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#connect-more-components-to-read-data-from-the-store).

> For example, rather than just connecting a `<UserList>` component and reading the entire array of users, have `<UserList>` retrieve a list of all user IDs, render list items as `<UserListItem userId={userId}>`, and have `<UserListItem>` be connected and extract its own user entry from the store.

This, though, sounds a bit contradicting to what has been encouraged earlier in "Usage with React" section to [separate *presentational* components from *container* components](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#presentational-and-container-components) where the presentational components are to read data from props, not from the store.

Does this mean that:

1. It is best practice to keep the number of presentational components to minimum, hence increasing the number of stateful components?
2. Or the connected components can also be actually stateless components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a Redux maintainer, and I wrote the Style Guide page.

The short answer is that the Redux docs have been written over time, and thus some of the older docs page are out of date.

The Style Guide is our latest and current advice on how you should write your app.

We're in the process of rewriting the Redux core docs.  That exact "Usage with React" page is something I intend to rewrite very soon, and when I do, I'll be dropping the terms "presentational" and "container" entirely.

I'd also encourage you to read my post [Thoughts on React Hooks, Redux, and Separation of Concerns](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/07/blogged-answers-thoughts-on-hooks/) and watch my React Boston 2019 talk on [Hooks, HOCs, and Tradeoffs](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/09/presentation-hooks-hocs-tradeoffs/) to get some more thoughts on how hooks change the way we think about writing components.

Comment: Thakn you, @markerikson! The talk is such a joy to watch. It is humble and reasonable, and gives me a fresh perspective now. Thanks again ‍♂️

Comment: You didn't answer this question directly. What's the better practice in different situations? And related paragraphs in the Style Guide page haven't been updated yet.

Comment: Not sure what "updates" you were expecting to see - the advice to "connect more components" is sufficient as-is in that page.  And I _did_ answer the question, by explaining that "we're in the process of changing the advice in our docs", and pointing to places where I've discussed the nuances and tradeoffs in the different approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Like everything in programming, there is a balance.

- On the one hand, you have separation of concerns, making sure each block of code is focusing on one task. This can help reduce the complexity of a given component.
- On the other hand, you have reduction of parameters, reducing the brittleness of your code by keeping track of fewer parameters at any given moment.

The first bullet is typically required when your state management is complex, or you have to manage server connections, and want to keep that work separate from the presentation to reduce confusion.

Redux takes care of that for you, by putting that code into the reducer. If you use the `connect()` higher-order component, that's exactly what you're doing: creating a component to translate state for your base presentation component. The `useSelector()` and `useDispatch()` hooks are another way of reducing the state management code in your component.

Redux stresses the second bullet because Redux's purpose is to reduce the clutter to the point that you don't need to separate your code into presentation and business logic components. Instead of passing several props back and forth, you can pass a single key, make a simple function inside your component to retrieve the data, and get on with the presentation directly.

The folks who wrote Redux also want to reassure folks that Redux is quite fast, and not to be afraid to use it generously.

My own experience is that Redux manages the business logic side of things well enough that I rarely need to create a separate wrapper component for business logic. The state code is a few lines calling hooks at the top, and that's it.

If I do have complex business logic, typically it involves deciding what state to display. That involves determining which key to use in my Redux state. So I might put all that logic into a wrapper, but the end result of the wrapper is a single key that my presentation component uses to pull the appropriate state from Redux.